# Custom 404 page won't allow additional edits

Tags: 2010, custom, 404

I was able to follow [these directions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/941329) to implement a `custom 404 page` in SharePoint 2010.

I wanted to make additional formatting changes to the custom page after implementation. including fixing a broken image link. But none of the changes seem to take. I tried different browsers with different nonexistent links and they all show the original version of the custom page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set custom 404 - Page Not found, first implement your custom page and deploy it as farm solution in Layouts folder. Once you deploy it into layouts folder execute below powersheell command.

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://test
$webApp.UpdateMappedPage([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication+SPCustomPage]::Error,"/_layouts/1033/Custom_Error.html") 
$webApp.Update()
```

This will update SharePoint default Page Not Found Error Page and sets your custom Page instead.

For more details: [Click Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2012/10/02/how-to-customize-error-page-page-not-found-and-access-denied-in-sharepoint-2010/)